# Hot to get select option value based on display name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML select element:

```
<select id="publisher" name="publisher">
  <option value="10">Google</option>
  <option value="11">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="14">Facebook</option>
  <option value="17">Hotmail</option>
</select>
```

How to get option value based on display name, like i want 14 based on display name Facebook using Jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var currentVal = $('#publisher').val(); //will return current selected value, numeric in your case
var facebookVal = $('#publisher').val('Facebook').val(); //will select facebook as current option and will fill facebookVal with value 14
```

Or, if you just wondering which value is for facebook, then:

```
var wonderVal = $('#publisher option:contains(Facebook)').val();
```

Hope this helped.